# Is there a way to resolve the Stylelint error for semicolons in CSS variables?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stylelint, scss-lint

- React.js
- Css in JS(Emotion)

It consists of the above.

Stylelint is configured as follows.

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "stylelint-config-standard",
    "./node_modules/prettier-stylelint/config.js",
  ],
  ignoreFiles: ["**/node_modules/**", "src/styles/**"],
  plugins: ["stylelint-order"],
  rules: {
    "declaration-empty-line-before": "never",
    indentation: 2,
    "no-missing-end-of-source-newline": null,
    "string-quotes": "single",
    "order/properties-alphabetical-order": true,
  },
};
```

CSS is as follows.

```js
import emotionReset from "emotion-reset";

const globalStyle = css`
  ${emotionReset};
`;
```

The following error message appears for `${emotionReset};`.

> Unexpected extra semicolon (no-extra-semicolons)stylelint(no-extra-semicolons)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY251.jpg)

Is there any way to resolve this error?
By the way, you will see the error, but the CSS is working.

---

I thought that disabling `no-extra-semicolons` would solve the problem, but there doesn't seem to be an option provided to disable it.
[no-extra-semicolons · stylelint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/no-extra-semicolons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a valid warning. You should be able to fix it by removing the semicolon from the highlighted line.

Replace:

```
  ${emotionReset};
```

with:

```
  ${emotionReset}
```

> By the way, you will see the error, but the CSS is working.

The extra semicolon generally won't break your CSS. But it doesn't *add* anything either, so it should be safe to remove it.

> I thought that disabling no-extra-semicolons would solve the problem, but there doesn't seem to be an option provided to disable it.

You can use `null` to disable a rule. See stylelint's [configuration docs for more details](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#rules).

Comment: `You can use null to disable a rule.` Yeah, but what's the rule? Lots of warnings about rules that don't exist in their docs, and disabling them by their name in the warning doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this rule will work for you

```
"no-extra-semicolons": [
 null,
  {
    "message": "Extra semi-colon."
  }
],
```